# Probability of failure in a machine

Tags: probability

I have 18 motors in a thermal power station.
If one of the motors "dies" because of the failure of some of the components (for example an injector pin).
What is the probability that one of the other motors dies for the same reason in a year?
I have the record of the fails of every motor in the thermal power station. There has been 12 fails of the injectors in diferent motors (one of them was the fail that made one of the motors "die")

P.s (sorry about any grammar mistake with my english)

Comment: One motor failing has no bearing on the probability that any other motor will fail. There is not enough information here to answer the question "What is the probability that one of the other motors dies for the same reason in a year?" Perhaps you are trying to use the failure data you have collected to estimate a failure rate. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

If the motors are the same model, then it's possible that the failure modes have the same probability for each motor (although they will be uncorrelated).

You can model the failure probabilities as a multinomial distribution. Then, you can estimate the probability of a similar failure by estimating the multinomial parameters using your data.

This [paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Teaching/CS340-Fall06/reading/bernoulli.pdf) has two methods for doing this: maximum likelihood estimation or (if your sample size is small), a Bayesian estimate using a flat Dirichlet Prior.

Comment: Thanks, I´m going to check! :)